# I have upgraded android studio to version 2.2.2 but receive an error

Tags: android-studio

This is my error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. >
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:

This my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anees.aneesdawran.osyar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: compile your app with gradle from command line and add the -info parameter to get a more detailled information. I think this might help us to help you.

Comment: Just restart the android studio it happens some time

Comment: i have restart the android studio.. its coming error again.